# How to access functions defined in js file inside the template of Polymer element?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, mixins, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I have created a function in ***global.function.js*** file as

```
function getData(flag) {
if (flag === 1) {
  return "one";
 } 
else {
  return "not one";
 }
}
```

which then is imported using ***custom-js-import.html*** element:

`<script src="global.function.js"></script>`

When I tried to access the above function in ***custom-element.html***, I am able to access it in the script part but not in the template part.
Is there any way I can access the function inside the HTML element?

```
<!-- custom-element.html -->
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="custom-js-import.html">

<dom-module id="custom-element">

  <template>
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <div>{{getData(1)}}</div><!-- Unable to access this from here -->
    <div>{{getLocalData()}}</div>
  </template>

<script>
  // Define the class for a new element called custom-element
  class CustomElement extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return "custom-element"; }
    constructor() {
        super();
      }

      ready(){
        super.ready();
        this.$.data.textContent = "I'm a custom-element.";
        console.log(getData(1));//can be easily accessed from here
      }

      getLocalData(){
        return "local";
      }

  }
  // Register the new element with the browser
  customElements.define(CustomElement.is, CustomElement);
</script>
</dom-module>
```

[Sample Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/bG3gPw?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Rico Kahler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5776910/rico-kahler) for suggesting me to use a [mixin](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins). Using [mixin](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins) solved my problem. You can view the full working sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XFzf8f?p=preview).

All the global functions can be defined in the mixin.

```
<!--custom-mixin.html-->
<script>
  const CustomMixin = superclass => class extends superclass {

static get properties() {
  return {};
}

connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
}

getData(flag) {
   if (flag === 1) {
    return "one(From Mixin)";
   } else {
    return "not one(From Mixin)";
   }
  }
 };
</script>
```

And remember to import the mixin file and add that mixin to your element.

```
<!-- custom-element.html -->
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="custom-mixin.html">

<dom-module id="custom-element">

  <template>
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <div>{{getData(1)}}</div>
    <!-- Unable to access this from here -->
    <div>{{getLocalData()}}</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    // Define the class for a new element called custom-element
    class CustomElement extends CustomMixin(Polymer.Element) {
        static get is() {
          return "custom-element";
        }
        constructor() {
          super();
        }

        ready() {
          super.ready();
          this.$.data.textContent = "I'm a custom-element.";
          console.log(getData(1)); //can be easily accessed from here
        }

        getLocalData() {
          return "local";
        }

      }
      // Register the new element with the browser
    customElements.define(CustomElement.is, CustomElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can access the function inside the HTML element?

Not really. In order to use data in a template you need to bind it to a property (Polymer calls this data binding).

Polymer's data binding system is designed for binding values to a template. Those values are typically just literals (e.g. strings and numbers) or plain ole javascript objects e.g. `{a: 'someval', b: 5}`. **Polymer's data binding system is *not* designed to bind functions to a template and you can't just use javascript inside of a template.** [(If you're really into that idea, check out React as a replacement to polymer)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx).

The polymer way to do what you're trying to do is to use a [computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property). Instead of calling a function inside the template, create a computed property that reacts to changes of other variables. When the state of a property changes, the computed property will change too. This state can be thought of as the argument of your function.

I think it's better just to see the code working yeah (tested in chrome)?

```html
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="custom-js-import.html">

<dom-module id="custom-element">

  <template>
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
    <label>
      <input type="number" value="{{flag::input}}">
    </label>
    <h1>from flag: [[flag]]</h1>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <div>{{boundComputedData}}</div><!-- Unable to access this from here -->
    <div>{{getLocalData()}}</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    // Define the class for a new element called custom-element
    class CustomElement extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return "custom-element";
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      getData(flag) {
        const flagAsNumber = parseInt(flag);
        if (flagAsNumber === 1) {
          return "one";
        } else {
          return "not one";
        }
      }

      ready() {
        super.ready();
        this.$.data.textContent = "I'm a custom-element.";
        console.log(this.getData(1)); //can be easily accessed from here
      }

      getLocalData() {
        return "local";
      }



      static get properties() {
        return {
          flag: {
            type: Number,
            value: 0
          },
          boundComputedData: {
            type: String,
            computed: 'getData(flag)'
          }
        };
      }

    }
    // Register the new element with the browser
    customElements.define(CustomElement.is, CustomElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<custom-element></custom-element>
```

So What I'm doing here is:

creating a computed property `boundComputedData` and setting the `computed` property to `'getData(flag)'` which will make it use the class function `getData`.

Now whenever the state the property `flag` changes, the computed property will update.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Rico, I am currently using similar concept of computed property. But, the problem is I need to implement the same thing in eight custom-elements. So, I was trying to avoid repetition.

Comment: @Ofisora trying using a [behavior](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors) or a [mixin](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#mixins) then